# Hamburger menu shows on screen on page load, then is not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My hamburger menu, when a page is loaded on mobile or in a resized browser window on desktop, will flash down the screen on every page load. The hamburger button is then not clickable - the cursor changes to show that there is a button, but no clicking will open the menu.

I've looked at the wayback machine archive of my page, in which the hamburger menu works fine, and I thought perhaps there was a problem on the current site with the ut-mm-trigger in that the style was set to display:none, as shown below.

I don't know what other information would be helpful - I'm not really sure what I'm doing. I have a wordpress site, and have removed all plugins as well as any other code I added to the theme, but was unable to resolve the issue. I've updated the versions of jquery and bootstrap, but that has not changed anything. The site is here: https://usapschool.org

```
<div class="ut-mm-trigger" style="display: none;">        
        <div id="ut-hamburger-wrap-mobile" class="ut-hamburger-wrap">
           <a id="ut-open-mobile-menu" class="ut-hamburger ut-hamburger--cross" type="button">
                <span></span>
            </a> 
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you've shared is HTML . HTML does not determine whether a hamburger will display the menu. What handles menu display is usually javascript or in some cases css. YOu have not shared sufficient information

Comment: If you edit your post and hit Ctrl-M, you should see how you can post a working example of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being hidden by a `display: none`, that has no counterpart to put it back on mobile which is where you need that code.
Add this to your mobile/tablet media query;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.ut-mm-trigger {display:block;}
}
```